# Place variable in dynamic option field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to place

```
var temp = results[i].get("place");
```

into

```
$("<option>****HERE***</option>").appendTo($department);
```

I have tried replacing the quotes/etc., but I cannot get it to work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried concatenation?

```
$("<option>" + temp + "</option>")
```

You could also use jQuery's own methods for adding text:

```
$("<option>").text(temp);
```